# Can "the day after tomorrow" be used as an adverb?

Tags: word-usage

I've come across this expression while having a conversation over the phone with a native English speaking friend. However, I am not sure if he said "at the day after tomorrow" or "the day after tomorrow".

Can this expression be used as a adverb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The day after tomorrow*, like *today*, *tomorrow*, *yesterday*, *this morning*, *tonight*, *next week* and *last year* does not usually take a preposition, so yes, it is usually used as an adverbial phrase.

Some temporal phrases do require a preposition (eg *in 2015*, *in March*), and for some a preposition is optional (eg *on Tuesday* vs *Tuesday*. The form without a preposition feels more colloquial to me, but I think it is more established in American English than in British).

Comment: Even if it did take a preposition, the preposition would not be 'at'.  In some contexts you might say, "*on* the day after tomorrow" Also you  can say '*by* the day after tomorrow'.